# How to export Access database table exceeding 4 million records to Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access, export

I have an Access database with 1 table with over 4 million records. I would like to read this in with Python, but the pyodbc module is giving me issues. Another approach I'm considering is to export the table to Excel, but Excel limits the number of rows to about 1.05 million. How do I partition the Access table into multiple sets of 1.05 million rows each so that all of the data can be exported into multiple .xlsx files?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SU. What's your end goal here? Putting 4m records into Excel sounds like it's going to be problematic.

Comment: Rather than export all, use SQL queries to select a *part* at a time, e.g. subdividing data set by alphabet, date or sort order.

Comment: One good way to do this, run multiple queries where each produce should a partial set of the data from the Table. After executing the query you can export it to Excel. And for entire exercise you can use VBA Macro too.